# Can't see my custom rules in Sonarqube after deployed

Tags: java, sonarqube

I need analyze source code of my projects, so i write my java custom rules reference to:
    https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules  example.
   Then I try to export my customer rules to an jar file and deploy to sonarqube's plugin folder and restart the server, then nothing happened...
   When I try to find my customer rule/plugin in Rules/Plugin page, I can't find it, where I did wrong??

I have written my rules by extends **BaseTreeVisitor** and add Rule annotation,and I extends **Plugin** interface to implement my own plugin.And here is build tag:

```
<artifactId>leons-Service-Check-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <pluginClass>com.leons.java.MyJavaRulesPlugin</pluginClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

in maven pom.xml.

Comment: Can you provide the java plugin version you are using? You should use version 3.6. Does your SQ instance have the java plugin (3.6) installed?

Comment: Yes,I've already installed java plugin 3.6 and I can see the java plugin in the 'unpdate center'->'installed plugin' page.And its status is installed,still I can see 338 rules of Java in 'rules' page.But I am unable to see my own plugin or rules in these two pages..........

Comment: And Michael, what do you mean about installed java plugin(3.6) in SQ instance? should I do some configures in the back-end side of SQ?